# Оборот - происхождение слова.

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы получить развёрнутое мнение об этимологии слова "оборот".

Comment: Развёрнутого мнения нет, есть предположение.
"Оборот" от "обернуть", фигура, завиток речи, в смысле "от така загогулина, понимашь..."

Answer (score 2):

http://tolkslovar.ru/o1626.html

Answer (score 2):

Слова *оборот* и *поворот* тесно связаны и корень у них явно один и тот же. Обычно пишут, что первоначально была форма 'обВорот', но потом согласный В исчез, выпал. До сих пор существуют варианты : оборачивать - обВорачивать, обернуть - обВернуть. Да и слово **обворот** иногда используется в отдельных значениях.

> Этимологический словарь русского языка Семенова
> **оборот**
> Древнерусское – обворот (от воротити – «вертеть»).
> Слово «оборот» появилось в русском языке в середине XII в.
> Данное слово происходит от глагола «воротити» – «воротить, вертеть, кружить». Тесно связано со словами «поворот», «ворот», «превращение» и т.д., поскольку все они происходят от единого общеславянского корня.